# MySQL REPEAT procedure from a list

Tags: mysql, repeat

**NOTICE**: In this question I am only interested in the general case, but for the sake of simplicity, I would consider a specific case.

Let's imagine I would like to create a table with columns taken from a list.

So, I would like to batch create tables from a list:

```
SET @list = "foo,bar,baz";
SET @query = '';

SET @query = 'CREATE TABLE foobar (';
-- FOREACH @list ASs name
SET @query = CONCAT(@query, name, ' INT,')
-- ENDFOREACH

SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ')'); -- Yes I need to remove the extra semicolon

PREPARE stm1;
FROM @query;
EXECUTE stm1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm1;
```

Unfortunately I haven't found how to do the repeat. My current solution is to create a dummy table with all names I could use:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO dummy (`name`) VALUES ('foo'), ('bar'), ('baz');
```

Then I can do:

```
SELECT name FROM dummy WHERE FIND_IN_SET(name, @list);
```

So I can do:

```
SELECT 
    @query := CONCAT(@query, ' ', 
   '...'
) 
FROM dummy 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(name, @list);
```

I there a way to simplify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use this trick:

```
SET @query = '';
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE foo(IN names VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
SET @myArrayOfValue = CONCAT(names, ',');
    WHILE (LOCATE(',', @myArrayOfValue) > 0)
    DO
        SET @value = LEFT(@myArrayOfValue, LOCATE(',',@myArrayOfValue) - 1);    
        SET @myArrayOfValue = SUBSTRING(@myArrayOfValue, LOCATE(',',@myArrayOfValue) + 1);

        -- BEGIN The code you want to repeat
        SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' CREATE TABLE ', @value, ' ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);');
        -- END
    END WHILE;
END
|
```

Then you can simply call your procedure:

```
CALL foo('foo,bar,baz');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `PREPARE` to prepare multiple queries separated by semicolons. You must do them one at a time.

```
mysql> set @sql = "select * from foo ; select * from bar";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'select * from bar' at line 1
```

I have no idea why so many developers want to use stored procedures in MySQL. They are terrible. There are no packages, no user-defined data types, no compiler, no debugger, and the documentation is poor.

The task you describe is easier to implement in any scripting language. Pick your favorite language, any of them are just as capable as the others for this task.

Here's an example in Ruby:

```
require 'Mysql2'
db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database => "test")

["foo", "bar", "baz"].each do |table|
  db.query("CREATE TABLE `#{table}` ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY )")
end
```

Compare this with the tricky string-splitting and concatenating, prepare and execute that's necessary when you use a stored procedure.

I don't use MySQL stored procedures and I don't recommend anyone else use them, except for exception cases. One case I have used stored procedures is to grant users the ability to run a few SQL statements against data they don't otherwise have privileges to view.

---

Here's a solution, tested on MySQL 5.6:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE the_worst_solution_for_this_task(IN tablenames TEXT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE i INT;
 DECLARE tablename VARCHAR(64);
 SELECT LENGTH(tablenames)-LENGTH(REPLACE(tablenames, ',', ''))+1 INTO i;
 WHILE i > 0
 DO
  SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablenames, ',', i), ',', -1)) INTO tablename;
  SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', tablename, '` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET i = i - 1;
 END WHILE;
END;;
DELIMITER ;

CALL the_worst_solution_for_this_task('foo,bar,baz');

SHOW TABLES;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| bar            |
| baz            |
| foo            |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Well, you are not answering my question. I have to agree, I did not know I can't use `PREPARE` to prepare multiple queries. I will edit and use another example, which does not change the question itself. Next, I cannot use Ruby, PHP or Python for this, I need to use MySQL.

Comment: That said you are perfectly right, stored procedures in MySQL are terrible with a poor documentation, but in some cases you have no other choices...